# How to rotate and flip LBP features in XML for multiple view face detection?

Tags: xml, face-detection, lbph-algorithm

For multiple view face detection, we can flip and rotate the LBP features/operators to detect different face poses. 
For example, we have XML with LBP features trained for 45 deg in plane rotated face, if we flip the LBP features we can detect the -45 deg in plane rotation as shown in the attached image.

That is mentioned in [this](http://media.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/%7Eimagevision/papers/FG04-113-WU_B.pdf) paper (page 3) and in [this](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2008/Jo-FaceDetectionUsingLBPfeatures.pdf) paper (page 3, second paragraph). 
My query is how to flip the LBP features. Say I have LBP features in the XML file as (Stage 0 is shown below). Then I also have rectangles at the end of the XML files. I flipped the rectangles as shown in the attached image. I tested with profile face XML with LBP features.

I flipped all rectangles as shown in the attached image, but it doesn't work. What are the things I still need to flip in XML file trained for right profile face. 
So that the new XML file can be used for left profile face.

```
<!-- stage 0 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>2</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-3.0878582596778870e-001</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 56 -753806256 1896960080 -266837675 -553430703
            -939425653 -275644159 -662055445 -71304225</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.9636164903640747e-001 7.1802616119384766e-001</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 46 -787246145 864096283 -117321441 320950355 402663867
            759873929 1577797887 993786587</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.4973531961441040e-001 5.8757579326629639e-001</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
```

[image].

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you did part of it correctly. However, you must also alter the `<internalNodes>` bits, since the comparisons are now mirrored and rotated. If you were to view the diagram in my answer to another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22565631/2809095), the comparison `R0 >= R4` becomes `R2 >= R4`, for instance, and the results of these comparisons go into bits 7 and 5 of the LBP, respectively. For a mirroring, you therefore need to compute a new LUT equivalent to the old one but with the LBP index undergoing three bit permutations: b7 <-> b5, b4 <-> b0, b1 <-> b3.