# opencv_traincascade number of features

Tags: opencv

When I train my classifier using opencv_traincascade by using local binary pattern (LBP), I get this written on console :

```
Number of unique features given windowSize [50,28] : 51408
```

How is this number calculated?

Comment: You can find some details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565531/understanding-opencv-lbp-implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with OpenCV, you can check the source code. It's basically computed from the window size.

That number comes out from `featureEvaluator->getNumFeatures()`. See [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4da91f9e6decee416f580402f55d943db1bf74a9/apps/traincascade/cascadeclassifier.cpp#L193):

```
 cout << "Number of unique features given windowSize [" 
      << _cascadeParams.winSize.width << "," 
      << _cascadeParams.winSize.height << "] : " 
      << featureEvaluator->getNumFeatures() << "" << endl;
```

This function just returns `numFeatures`. See [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/apps/traincascade/traincascade_features.h#L86):

```
 int getNumFeatures() const { return numFeatures; }
```

For LPB features, this number is computed in [`generateFeatures`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/apps/traincascade/lbpfeatures.cpp#L35):

```
void CvLBPEvaluator::generateFeatures()
{
    int offset = winSize.width + 1;
    for( int x = 0; x < winSize.width; x++ )
        for( int y = 0; y < winSize.height; y++ )
            for( int w = 1; w <= winSize.width / 3; w++ )
                for( int h = 1; h <= winSize.height / 3; h++ )
                    if ( (x+3*w <= winSize.width) && (y+3*h <= winSize.height) )
                         features.push_back( Feature(offset, x, y, w, h ) );
    numFeatures = (int)features.size();
}
```

Comment: Look into your opencv installation folder. I can't look for the exact path now, but it'll be there ;D

Comment: Do you know explanation of code above? I have been learning LBP for some time, but can't understand logics behind these few lines of code. For example, why is width and height divided by 3?

Comment: I don't know that. You can see if somebody else has a clear explanation for that. (You may want to un-accept the answer, since answered question don't attract many other users)

Comment: Maybe the 3 is related to [LBP 3x3 grid size](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/lbp-fundamentals.html)? The LBP size increases but you have always a 3x3 grid size (the cell size will increase). You should run through the algorithm with a paper, draw for each iteration the pattern and for a specific winSize value to fully understand the code in my opinion.